# What is the difference between `tf.keras.losses` vs. `tf.losses`, or `tf.keras.optimizers` vs. `tf.optimizers`?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, tensorflow2.x

Is there any difference between the followings?

```
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
loss2 = tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
optimizer2 = tf.optimizers.Adam()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have no difference with each other and are just aliases of each other. You can find this information in the corresponding documentation pages [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses):

[image: TensorFlow losses documentation]

and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers):

[image: TensorFlow optimizers documentation]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use keras with tensorflow as backend, meaning that you can use all of tensorflow's functionality through keras, as well as some additional features making it higher level.

This means that they should be the same.